# SQLAlchemy: Adding an instance to session causes other instances to be added automatically

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

I've declared two objects (`Group` and `Family`) with a one-to-many relationship, where each `Family` can belong to a `Group`. Please consider the following reproducible example:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, UniqueConstraint, String, Integer, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, sessionmaker

Base = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///test.sqlite')

class Group(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'Group'
    __table_args__ = (
        UniqueConstraint('Id'),
    )
    
    id = Column('Id', String, primary_key=True, nullable=False, autoincrement=False)
    name = Column('Name', String, nullable=False)

    families = relationship('Family', back_populates='group')

class Family(Base):
    
    __tablename__ = 'Family'
    __table_args__ = tuple(UniqueConstraint('Id'))

    id = Column('Id', String, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    name = Column('StemId', String, nullable=False)    
    group_id = Column('GroupId', Integer, ForeignKey('Group.Id'))

    group = relationship('Group', back_populates='families')

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

SessionMaker = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = SessionMaker()
```

Next, I'm creating two transient instances of `Family` and adding the same transient instance of `Group` to them.

```
CrustaceanGroup = Group(id='crustaceans', name='Crustaceans')
Shrimp = Family(id='shrimp', name='Shrimp', group=CrustaceanGroup)
Lobster = Family(id='lobster', name='Lobster', group=CrustaceanGroup)
```

Now the part that confuses me: When I only add `Shrimp` to the `session`, `Lobster` appears to be added automatically:

```
session.add(Shrimp)
session.query(Family).all() # This gives me both objects!
```

However, if these are not linked by `CrustaceanGroup`, adding `Shrimp` results in the expected behavior (only adding one instance to the session):

```
Shrimp = Family(id='shrimp', name='Shrimp')
Lobster = Family(id='lobster', name='Lobster')
session.add(Shrimp)
session.query(Family).all() # resulting in only one instance, which I desire
```

Why is this happening and how can I avoid other instances being added automatically, as shown in the first case? Thank you!

Comment: The docs [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/cascades.html#save-update) explain the behaviour.  I'm not entirely sure how to prevent it. Setting `cascade_backrefs=False` ([docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/cascades.html#controlling-cascade-on-backrefs)) on relationships where is not desired _might_ work: i'm not sure whether 2 x back_populates == backref in this situation.

Comment: As pointed out by @snakecharmerb, this is the one of the advantages to using something like `sqlalchememy` - in order to track dependencies automatically withing the _Unit of Work_.
Just curious: why would you want a different behavior?

Comment: Thanks, I see the possible advantage but this tends to cause errors with `session.add()` and unique constraints when I'm attempting to link objects that may or may not be in the db.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are seeing the older cascade behaviour for dependent objects which will change in version 2.0. Running under version 1.4 with `SQLALCHEMY_WARN_20=1`, this code displays the behaviour you describe,

```py
with Session(engine) as session:
    CrustaceanGroup = Group(id='crustaceans', name='Crustaceans')
    Shrimp = Family(id='shrimp', name='Shrimp', group=CrustaceanGroup)
    session.add(Shrimp)
    Lobster = Family(id='lobster', name='Lobster', group=CrustaceanGroup)
    session.commit()

with Session(engine) as session:
    print(session.scalars(select(Family.id)).all())
    # ['lobster', 'shrimp']
```

but it also emits the warning

> RemovedIn20Warning: "Family" object is being merged into a Session along the backref cascade path for relationship "Group.families"; in SQLAlchemy 2.0, this reverse cascade will not take place.  Set cascade_backrefs to False in either the relationship() or backref() function for the 2.0 behavior; or to set globally for the whole Session, set the future=True flag
>
> Lobster = Family(id='lobster', name='Lobster', group=CrustaceanGroup)

Note that `cascade_backrefs=` is going away on 2.0. (It will be ignored.)

If we use a 2.0 Session (`future=True`) then we get the behaviour you desire

```py
with Session(engine, future=True) as session:
    CrustaceanGroup = Group(id='crustaceans', name='Crustaceans')
    Shrimp = Family(id='shrimp', name='Shrimp', group=CrustaceanGroup)
    session.add(Shrimp)
    Lobster = Family(id='lobster', name='Lobster', group=CrustaceanGroup)
    session.commit()

with Session(engine) as session:
    print(session.scalars(select(Family.id)).all())
    # ['shrimp']
```

but we also get the warning

> SAWarning: Object of type  not in session, add operation along 'Group.families' will not proceed

letting us know that the `Lobster` object has not been cascaded into the Session.